# Knockout computed doesnt update properties in view

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

i use knockout´s computed to display a filtered dataset. It is triggered by changing observable filters.
i want to display a list with matching entries and a list with not matching entries and the reason why it is not matching.
So basically i add a new property to the entry with the reasons why the entry is excluded. The first time it is rendered works fine, the new property shows the correct exclusion reasons, whenever i change a filter the lists are correctly updated but the exclusion reasons stay the same in the view even though they are different in the result returned by the observable.

To visualize the error, i made i minimal working example.
In the example the entry "joe" is excluded and the exclusion reasons are correct, if you change filter2 to "small" there should be an extra reason why joe is excluded but its not showing up, if you click the button "show actual" it just renders the actual output of the computed and you see the correct exclusion reasons.

So why dont they automatically change in the view? is there any way to get this to the result i expect ?

[JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE TO PLAY AROUND](http://jsfiddle.net/bWFtB/130/)

here is the js code (jquery and knockout)

```js
var viewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.filter1 = ko.observable("green");
    self.filter2 = ko.observable("big");
    self.entries = ko.observableArray([
    {name:'Joe',f1:'yellow',f2:'big'},
    {name:'Brad',f1:'red',f2:'small'},
    {name:'Anton',f1:'green',f2:'big'},
    {name:'Pete',f1:'red',f2:'small'},
    {name:'Cedric',f1:'green',f2:'smaller'}
    ]);
    self.filteredEntries = ko.computed( function() {
        filter1 = self.filter1();
        filter2 = self.filter2();
        ens_excluded = [];
        ens = jQuery.grep(self.entries(), function( n, i ) {

          expression = true;
          excludeReasons =[];

          t1 = n.f1 == filter1
          if(!t1){
            expression = false;
            excludeReasons.push("f1 no match")
          }

          t2 = n.f2 == filter2;
          if(!t2){
            expression = false;
            excludeReasons.push("f2 no match")
          }

          if(!expression){
            n.excludeReasons = excludeReasons;
            ens_excluded.push(n)
          }
          return expression;
        });
        return {
          include:ens,
          exclude:ens_excluded
         };        
    });
};
vm = new viewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);


$(document).on("click",".showActual",function(){
  ens_excluded = vm.filteredEntries().exclude;
  $('.actual').empty();
  $.each(ens_excluded, function(i,val){
    $('.actual').append("<p><span>"+val.name+"("+val.f1+","+val.f2+")</span> <small>"+val.excludeReasons.toString()+"</small></p>")
   })
})
```

```html
<div class="body">
    <div>
        <label for="fname">Filter1:</label>
         <select name="" data-bind="value: vm.filter1" id="">
           <option value="green">green</option>
           <option value="red">red</option>
         </select>
        <label for="fname">Filter2:</label>
         <select name="" data-bind="value: vm.filter2" id="">
           <option value="big">big</option>
           <option value="small">small</option>
         </select>
    </div>

    <hr />

    <strong>included:</strong>
    <div data-bind="foreach:vm.filteredEntries().include">
      <p data-bind="text:$data.name+' ('+$data.f1+', '+$data.f2+')'"></p>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <strong>excluded:</strong>
    <div data-bind="foreach:vm.filteredEntries().exclude">
    <p> <span data-bind="text:$data.name+' ('+$data.f1+', '+$data.f2+')'"></span> <small data-bind="text:$data.excludeReasons.toString()"></small> </p>
    </div>

    <button class="showActual" >Show Acutal</button>
    <div class="actual">

    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: *"JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE TO PLAY AROUND"* Even better, put the live version **in your question** using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)). (Edit: I've done it for you this time.) *(not my dv)*

Comment: *"In the example the entry "joe" is excluded and the exclusion reasons are correct"* What reasons should we see? *"if you change filter2 to "small" there should be an extra reason why joe is excluded but its not showing up"* ***What*** extra reason?

Comment: thanks for pointing this out and also doing it for me =) i´m not familiar with SO snippets

Comment: FWIW, not bothering to capitalize and punctuate correctly may well make people who can help you just move on to the next question. Similarly, the more concise (both the text and example), the a better.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder when you change f2 to small you should see "f1 no match,f2 no match" for joe because both filters not matching

Comment: you should see the difference when you click "show Actual"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the subject of the `foreach` isn't the computed (`vm.filteredEntries`), it's the array the computed's object has as a property (`vm.filteredEntries().exclude`):

```
<div data-bind="foreach:vm.filteredEntries().exclude">
<p> <span data-bind="text:$data.name+' ('+$data.f1+', '+$data.f2+')'"></span> <small data-bind="text:$data.excludeReasons.toString()"></small> </p>
</div>
```

Instead, ensure that you're relying on the computed directly in some way. There are several ways, but without changing your viewmodel, `with` works:

```
<!-- ko with: vm.filteredEntries -->
<div data-bind="foreach:exclude">
<p> <span data-bind="text:$data.name+' ('+$data.f1+', '+$data.f2+')'"></span> <small data-bind="text:$data.excludeReasons.toString()"></small> </p>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Example:

```js
var viewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.filter1 = ko.observable("green");
    self.filter2 = ko.observable("big");
    self.entries = ko.observableArray([
    {name:'Joe',f1:'yellow',f2:'big'},
    {name:'Brad',f1:'red',f2:'small'},
    {name:'Anton',f1:'green',f2:'big'},
    {name:'Pete',f1:'red',f2:'small'},
    {name:'Cedric',f1:'green',f2:'smaller'}
    ]);
    self.filteredEntries = ko.computed( function() {
        filter1 = self.filter1();
        filter2 = self.filter2();
        ens_excluded = [];
        ens = jQuery.grep(self.entries(), function( n, i ) {

          expression = true;
          excludeReasons =[];

          t1 = n.f1 == filter1
          if(!t1){
            expression = false;
            excludeReasons.push("f1 no match")
          }

          t2 = n.f2 == filter2;
          if(!t2){
            expression = false;
            excludeReasons.push("f2 no match")
          }

          if(!expression){
            n.excludeReasons = excludeReasons;
            ens_excluded.push(n)
          }
          return expression;
        });
        return {
          include:ens,
          exclude:ens_excluded
         };        
    });
};
vm = new viewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);


$(document).on("click",".showActual",function(){
  ens_excluded = vm.filteredEntries().exclude;
  $('.actual').empty();
  $.each(ens_excluded, function(i,val){
    $('.actual').append("<p><span>"+val.name+"("+val.f1+","+val.f2+")</span> <small>"+val.excludeReasons.toString()+"</small></p>")
   })
})
```

```html
<div class="body">
    <div>
        <label for="fname">Filter1:</label>
         <select name="" data-bind="value: vm.filter1" id="">
           <option value="green">green</option>
           <option value="red">red</option>
         </select>
        <label for="fname">Filter2:</label>
         <select name="" data-bind="value: vm.filter2" id="">
           <option value="big">big</option>
           <option value="small">small</option>
         </select>
    </div>

    <hr />

    <strong>included:</strong>
    <!-- ko with: vm.filteredEntries() -->
    <div data-bind="foreach:include">
      <p data-bind="text:$data.name+' ('+$data.f1+', '+$data.f2+')'"></p>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <hr>
    <strong>excluded:</strong>
    <!-- ko with: vm.filteredEntries -->
    <div data-bind="foreach:exclude">
    <p> <span data-bind="text:$data.name+' ('+$data.f1+', '+$data.f2+')'"></span> <small data-bind="text:$data.excludeReasons.toString()"></small> </p>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->

    <button class="showActual" >Show Acutal</button>
    <div class="actual">

    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

---

Side note: The code also falls prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html)* by not declaring several variables used in the `grep` callback. Be sure to declare your variables (in the narrowest scope possible).

* *(disclosure: that's a post on my anemic little blog)*

Comment: thank you so much for your grade black belt knockout and general js ninja, you saved my day!!